# What means in a A/B testing to have no data for the parameter confidence level?

Tags: commerce-cloud, demandware, ab-testing

I did run an A/B testing in my online shop, and I received the reports of the testing. In the reports, there is no data for *Confidence Level* "CL". What does that mean?
See the screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific on which Salesforce product the shop is running? Are we talking Salesforce Commerce Cloud?

Comment: Hi @LukasLunow, the online shop is running in the Salesforce Commerce Cloud, correct.